# How do I reference a project with the SqlServerTypes nuget package in an ASP.Net Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core

I've converted my ASP.Net Core project to target the .net 4.5.2 framework.

I then added a reference to a .net 4.5.2 class library project and that seemed to succeed.

I then built the web project and got the error:

> Failed to make the following project runnable: WebCore451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)
>   reason: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Other Code\Experiments\WebCore451\Dep\bin\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types.11.0.2\nativebinaries\x64\msvcr100.dll'.
>   WebCore451    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262

The error message says it's looking for the path:
`D:\Other Code\Experiments\WebCore451\Dep\bin\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types.11.0.2\nativebinaries\x64\msvcr100.dll`

The dll exists in the nuget package folders:  `($solution)\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.types.11.0.2\nativebinaries\x64\msvcr100.dll`

And it also exists in the referenced project build output:
`($project)\bin\($build)` as it's copied on build.

But neither of those match the path it's looking in.

Comment: did you find a clean solution?

Comment: Nope, but I reported the issue here: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/758